# Bayesian inference of non-homogeneous Markov transition matrix

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, gaussian-process, dirichlet-distribution, transition-matrix

The data consists of several discrete-time Markov chains, indexed by a global time. I assume all the chains are governed by the same transition matrix, but that this can change in time. I want to perform Bayesian inference on the time-varying transition matrix, with a prior that it varies smoothly in time. This is in the context of a Gibbs sampler, and I'm particularly interested in drawing samples from the distribution of transition matrices at each time point.

In the homogeneous case, I had been using a Dirichlet-multinomial distribution, taking into account all transitions. To tackle the non-homogeneous case, a first idea is to use a Dirichlet-multinomial distribution at each time point, using all the transitions observed at that time point. The chains mostly overlap in time, but the number of transitions observed at a given time point can vary from 1 to 100. I'm concerned that for time points with few observed transitions, the inferred time-varying probabilities could be non-smooth. One possibility for the lack of data at some time points would be to group together data of consecutive points, and assume they are governed by the same transition matrix (decreasing the time resolution).

Do you have any suggestions? I wonder about the possibility of incorporating a Gaussian process prior over some parametrization of the transition matrix.

EDIT: improve the question

Comment: What do you mean by "several" Markov chains? And when you write "distribution over the transition matrix", do you mean sampling a Markov transition matrix?

Comment: I've rephrased the question, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Sorry, this remains unclear to me. Are you talking of doing Bayesian inference on the transition matrices? But then how do you account for time-heterogeneity?

Comment: I've done some edits. I want to do Bayesian inference on multiple transition matrices (one for each time point), and looking for a way to incorporate a smoothness prior.